# Write to remote file java

Tags: java

How can I write to remote file in server? I try this but I can´t

```
try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("http://myserver/file.txt"));
    out.write("Hello");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   //handle exception
}
```

Comment: are you running http server and want to read/write file from http server?

Comment: FileWriter doesn't accept a url in any of it's constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FTP library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) from Apache to get the file in to your local, modify it, then ftp it back.

2nd option, if you don't want to do heavy text modifying is to use [sshExec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html). It lets you run commands on the server you connect to.

3rd option, execute the class on the server that the txt file exists.

Comment: do you know what type of server is running there?

Comment: @javaseeker each of these libraries are server agnostic